# Setting subview to non "transformable"?

Tags: ios

I have a container `UIView` that contains a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`, as follows:

```
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.clipToBounds = true

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: containerView.bounds)
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Some Image")
containerView.addSubview(imageView)

let labelView = UILabel(frame: containerView.bounds)
labelView.text = "Some Label"
containerView.addSubview(label)
```

I now want to stretch the x-axis of the `containerView` but keep the label untransformed, i.e. just stretch the `containerView` and the `imageView`. I have at the moment:

```
containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1)
```

but this also stretches the `label`. Any solution for making the label "non-transformable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the label outside of the container. Or, and this is slightly hacky, you could try giving the label the *inverse* of the container transformation:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(containerView.transform)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The hack works but not when I include it in an animation - does are a bizarre zoom in/out dance. How can I remove the label from the container and add it back to view at that position? I've tried `labelView.removeFromSuperview()` and then `view.addSubview(labelView)`, which adds the view back but the transformation still gets applied to it ...

Comment: You need to find the container of the container, and add the view there (`container.superview.addSubview(labelView)`). If you're using auto-layout, you'll need to update your constraints to handle the fact it's not a sibling of the other contained elements (which may be tricky). If you're computing the layout by hand, you can fiddle until you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you apply transform to `containerView`, then all its subviews will be also transformed(`labelView` and `imageView`).

Please add the label outside the container view so it will not transformed.